# Scenario where HTTP Response is not fragmented but request is fragmented

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

In our application, we are using apache tomcat webserver running in 8081.

We observed one behavior where HTTP POST Requests from clients are getting fragmented whereas HTTP Response "200 OK" is not getting fragmented. This we observed by collecting iptraces.

Our ETH MTU value is 1500 Bytes.

## Sample POST Request which is fragmented:

```
===( 331 bytes received on interface en0 )==== 13:50:01.040393849
ETHERNET packet : [ 00:26:cb:eb:df:7f -> 00:1a:64:47:3c:02 ]  type 800  (IP)
IP header breakdown:
    < SRC =   172.30.17.142 >  
    < DST =      10.16.0.72 >  (un51sv01_if0)
    ip_v=4, ip_hl=20, ip_tos=0, ip_len=317, ip_id=57225, ip_off=0 DF
    ip_ttl=62, ip_sum=942d, ip_p = 6 (TCP)
TCP header breakdown:
    <source port=43795, destination port=8081 >
    th_seq=2849969884, th_ack=3790782429
    th_off=5, flags<PUSH | ACK>
    th_win=49680, th_sum=ba63, th_urp=0
00000000     504f5354 202f6973 61736f61 702f656e     |POST /isasoap/en|
00000010     64706f69 6e742f49 6e766f6b 65417070     |dpoint/InvokeApp|
00000020     53657276 69636549 46204854 54502f31     |ServiceIF HTTP/1|
00000030     2e310d0a 436f6e74 656e742d 54797065     |.1..Content-Type|
00000040     3a207465 78742f78 6d6c3b20 63686172     |: text/xml; char|
00000050     7365743d 7574662d 380d0a41 63636570     |set=utf-8..Accep|
00000060     743a2074 6578742f 786d6c2c 20746578     |t: text/xml, tex|
00000070     742f6874 6d6c2c20 696d6167 652f6769     |t/html, image/gi|
00000080     662c2069 6d616765 2f6a7065 672c202a     |f, image/jpeg, *|
00000090     3b20713d 2e322c20 2a2f2a3b 20713d2e     |; q=.2, */*; q=.|
000000a0     320d0a53 4f415041 6374696f 6e3a2022     |2..SOAPAction: "|
000000b0     220d0a55 7365722d 4167656e 743a204a     |"..User-Agent: J|
000000c0     6176612f 312e362e 305f3831 0d0a486f     |ava/1.6.0_81..Ho|
000000d0     73743a20 31302e31 362e302e 37323a38     |st: 10.16.0.72:8|
000000e0     3038310d 0a436f6e 6e656374 696f6e3a     |081..Connection:|
000000f0     206b6565 702d616c 6976650d 0a436f6e     | keep-alive..Con|
00000100     74656e74 2d4c656e 6774683a 20333634     |tent-Length: 364|
00000110     390d0a0d 0a                             |9....           |
```

## Now the fragmented second packet start:

```
====( 1434 bytes received on interface en0 )==== 13:50:01.040697474
ETHERNET packet : [ 00:26:cb:eb:df:7f -> 00:1a:64:47:3c:02 ]  type 800  (IP)
IP header breakdown:
    < SRC =   172.30.17.142 >  
    < DST =      10.16.0.72 >  (un51sv01_if0)
    ip_v=4, ip_hl=20, ip_tos=0, ip_len=1420, ip_id=57227, ip_off=0 DF
    ip_ttl=62, ip_sum=8fdc, ip_p = 6 (TCP)
TCP header breakdown:
    <source port=43795, destination port=8081 >
    th_seq=2849970161, th_ack=3790782429
    th_off=5, flags<ACK>
    th_win=49680, th_sum=f8e9, th_urp=0
00000000     3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231     |<?xml version="1|
00000010     2e302220 656e636f 64696e67 3d225554     |.0" encoding="UT|
00000020     462d3822 3f3e0a3c 656e763a 456e7665     |F-8"?>.<env:Enve|
00000030     6c6f7065 20786d6c 6e733a65 6e763d22     |lope xmlns:env="|
00000040     68747470 3a2f2f73 6368656d 61732e78     |http://schemas.x|
00000050     6d6c736f 61702e6f 72672f73 6f61702f     |mlsoap.org/soap/|
00000060     656e7665 6c6f7065 2f222078 6d6c6e73     |envelope/" xmlns|
00000070     3a787364 3d226874 74703a2f 2f777777     |:xsd="http://www|
00000080     2e77332e 6f72672f 32303031 2f584d4c     |.w3.org/2001/XML|
00000090     53636865 6d612220 786d6c6e 733a7873     |Schema" xmlns:xs|
```

Similar to above, there is another packet.

## Now the Final packet of ~950 Octets:

```
====( 943 bytes received on interface en0 )==== 13:50:01.040713619
ETHERNET packet : [ 00:26:cb:eb:df:7f -> 00:1a:64:47:3c:02 ]  type 800  (IP)
IP header breakdown:
    < SRC =   172.30.17.142 >  
    < DST =      10.16.0.72 >  (un51sv01_if0)
    ip_v=4, ip_hl=20, ip_tos=0, ip_len=929, ip_id=57229, ip_off=0 DF
    ip_ttl=62, ip_sum=91c5, ip_p = 6 (TCP)
TCP header breakdown:
    <source port=43795, destination port=8081 >
    th_seq=2849972921, th_ack=3790782429
    th_off=5, flags<PUSH | ACK>
    th_win=49680, th_sum=32ac, th_urp=0
00000000     74612069 643d2249 44313122 20787369     |ta id="ID11" xsi|
00000010     3a747970 653d226e 73313a49 6e766f6b     |:type="ns1:Invok|
00000020     65417070 44617461 223e3c64 61746154     |eAppData"><dataT|
.....
```

After some internal processing by our application, we send 200 OK and HTTP Response.

## HTTP 200 OK Response

```
====( 3209 bytes transmitted on interface en0 )==== 13:50:01.041804849
ETHERNET packet : [ 00:1a:64:47:3c:02 -> 00:00:0c:07:ac:32 ]  type 800  (IP)
IP header breakdown:
    < SRC =      10.16.0.72 >  (un51sv01_if0)
    < DST =   172.30.17.142 >  
    ip_v=4, ip_hl=20, ip_tos=0, ip_len=3195, ip_id=60324, ip_off=0
    ip_ttl=60, ip_sum=ffff, ip_p = 6 (TCP)
TCP header breakdown:
    <source port=8081, destination port=43574 >
    th_seq=3486085705, th_ack=3771812741
    th_off=5, flags<PUSH | ACK>
    th_win=65535, th_sum=564, th_urp=0
00000000     48545450 2f312e31 20323030 204f4b0d     |HTTP/1.1 200 OK.|
00000010     0a416363 6570743a 20746578 742f786d     |.Accept: text/xm|
00000020     6c2c2074 6578742f 68746d6c 2c20696d     |l, text/html, im|
00000030     6167652f 6769662c 20696d61 67652f6a     |age/gif, image/j|
00000040     7065672c 202a3b20 713d2e32 2c202a2f     |peg, *; q=.2, */|
00000050     2a3b2071 3d2e320d 0a436f6e 74656e74     |*; q=.2..Content|
```

Please note from above that the length of packet received on en0 is "3209" for 200 OK HTTP Response which is actually the entire Response. But it is exceeding MTU of ethernet...

Our MTU value is default - 1500 bytes

```
un51sv01# lsattr -El en0 |grep mtu
mtu           1500          Maximum IP Packet Size for This Device     True
```

Can somebody throw light into why it is happening this way?

```
Change / Show Characteristics of an Ethernet Adapter

Type or select values in entry fields.
Press Enter AFTER making all desired changes.

                                                    [Entry Fields]
Ethernet Adapter                                    ent0
Description                                         Logical Host Ethernet Port (lp-hea)
Status                                              Available
Location
Request Transmit and Receive Jumbo Frames           no                                                                                      +
Enable hardware Transmit TCP segmentation           yes                                                                                     +
Enable receive TCP segment aggregation              yes                                                                                     +
Enable hardware Transmit checksum                   yes                                                                                     +
Enable hardware Receive checksum                    yes                                                                                     +
Requested media speed                               Auto_Negotiation                                                                        +
Enable ALTERNATE ETHERNET address                   no                                                                                      +
ALTERNATE ETHERNET address                         [0x000000000000]                                                                         +
Apply change to DATABASE only                       no                                                                                      +
```

The above indicate Jumbo Frames are not enabled.

Thanks,
Sashi

Comment: I agree. Packets can get fragmented. And reassembled. What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: Have you got jumbo frames enabled on your LAN?

Comment: @EJP, The actual Problem is The response is in "3209" bytes transmitted in whereas the request is fragmented by ~1500 Bytes.

Comment: @AndyBrown Jumbo Frames can have higher MTU. I will check on that.

Comment: Jumbo Frames are not enabled. You can check the edited question itself for the configuration I checked!!!